# Can the 290 Theorem be refined/sharpened to include special conditions?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

[The 290 theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems) states

> If a positive-definite quadratic form with integer coefficients
>   represents the twenty-nine integers $1$, $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $10$, $13$, $14$, $15$, $17$, $19$, $21$, $22$, $23$, $26$, $29$, $30$, $31$, $34$, $35$, $37$, $42$, $58$, $93$, $110$, $145$, $203$, and $290$, then it represents all positive integers.

Assume that I have such a form, *e.g.,*
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dw^2\!,$$
which represents all 29 “critical integers”, so that by the theorem the form represents all positive integers.

Now assume further that I can prove one or more conditions on how the form actually represents one or more of the “critical integers“, *e.g.*, say I can prove that $110$ can only be represented by the form if $x+y-z=1$.

**QUESTION:** Can it be shown that there exist an infinite number of positive integers subject to the extra condition(s)? Put another way, can the 290 Theorem can be refined/sharpened to show that any conditions which are required to represent all 29 of the “critical integers” are also required to represent all positive integers?

Comment: If you had $x+y-z=0$, then you could substitute one variable out and just examine the resulting form in fewer variables. Given $x+y-z=1$, though, I suspect life will be more difficult. But I don't understand the precise question you're asking....

Comment: @GregMartin: I've edited the title and question to try to clarify. I hope it worked.

Comment: @GregMartin: The first two sentences of your comment may prove very helpful… If I can use the conditions to derive _another_ form, and then show that the derived form _doesn’t_ represent all 29 critical integers, then the problem is reduced to showing that the 290 Theorem is “if and only if” [which may already have been done]. Thanks!

Comment: You have ***not*** given a quadratic form. You have given a quadratic polynomial. A quadratic form in three variables, positive, cannot represent all positive integers. This is proved in Conway's little book, for example.

Comment: @WillJagy: Hmm… Well, that's a serious problem for my current work. But I'm still interested in the answer when a quadratic form _is_ correctly given. So I've edited my question, and will work on the quadratic _polynomial_ issue separately. Thanks.

Comment: The 290 theorem is if-and-only-if, in fact: the finite list has been tested and shown to be optimal.